# Bash Total Folder Size (not-rounded)

Tags: bash, size

What is the best way best command to find non-rounded folder size, just like GUI dialog shows.
For example, when I click on folder and look at properties it gives me size simular to this "30.4 MB"

When I use "du" command it gives me rounded value.

```
du -s folder/
32880   folder/
```

But what I need is value => 30.4 MB etc. So I want to be abel to calculate total folder size but with precition size (not-rounded). Please post only the shortest commands possible, and not very long commands or functions. Thank you.

Because when I run this following command it rounds the size:

```
du -hs folder/
33M  folder/
```

So I would like to convert **32880** to **30.4 MB** just like it shows in folder properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "32880" is not rounded. I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you want a value with the size modifier appended at the end, use `du -sh`

Comment: I would like to convert 32880 to 30.4 MB =) Because when I run "du -hs folder/" then its rounded. Sorry!

Comment: Looks like folder properties dialog in XFCE and du or ls show diferent size. Properties dialog seems to round sizes way too much. So I will stick to du or ls and then extract and convert the value from that. Thanks.

Comment: I guess that works. One thing I did before was do an ls then just pipe to a grep to grab the values.

Comment: Oh, I know where the problem is. It doesn't do rounding, it's just that one does it base-1024 and the other does it base-1000. So they give different values, 1024 bytes might be 1 KB or 1.02 KB.